# How set combobox value when user selects a value in another combobox

Tags: javafx

I need help on a form which serves to add new gun. I have some comboBox, one of them has a text editor(ControlFX-textfields) when I type a gun model value it will show the preexisting ones, if I choose one those values I want the others ones (caliber, maker, type)  gets the corresponding values for that model like so:  choosing “PT100” on model, caliber gets “.40”, type gets “PISTOL” and maker gets “TAURUS”. I have all my models set on db. The problem is when a model has more the one values either for caliber, type or makers, for example: the model “CBC”, “puma”, “rifle”, it has 2 caliber possible “.38” and “357”. For now I have tried the follow for the caliber's comboBox:

```
modelo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {

            List<Modelo> list = listModelo.stream().filter(m -> m.getModeloNome().equals(newValue))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());                

               for(Modelo a: list){
                   if(list.size() == 1){
                       calibreBox.setValue(a.getCalibre());
                       tipoBox.setValue(a.getTipoArma());
                       marcaBox.setValue(a.getMarcaArma());
                   }if(list.size()> 1){
                       System.out.println(a.getCalibre());
                       calibrelist.clear();
                       List<String>  cal = new ArrayList<>();
                       cal.add(a.getCalibre());
                       calibrelist = FXCollections.observableList(cal);

               }
            }

        }
    });
```

When there is only one model, there is no problem at all.
also I wanna achieve:
When I type a model that does not exists on my db, the others combos should keep preexisting values from db.

What the best way to get all this done???

Comment: So if a model has two possible calibers, for instance, there will be two of the same model in the list. Correct? And what exactly do you want to do when a gun has two possible calibers? Do you want to set the value to the caliber first encountered, or add them to the list of options in the combobox?

Comment: I want to clear the preexisting ObservableList and then add those two calibers, not to set. Then the user will choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to instantiate the calibreList again by doing `calibrelist = FXCollections.observableList(cal);`. If calibreList is the list that contains the items of the `ComboBox`, which has been added to the ComboBox by doing `caliberComboBox.setItems(calibreList);`, then you need to manipulate that original list instead of instantiating it again.

So instead of `calibrelist = FXCollections.observableList(cal);`, do `calibrelist.add(a.getCalibre);`

Note the difference between `comboBox.setItems(calibreList)` and `comboBox.getItems().addAll(calibreList)` by the way. When you do `setItems(calibreList)` you can manipulate `calibreList` later on by using that reference, e.g. adding items to the `ComboBox` by doing `calibreList.add(".357");`. But if you use `getItems().addAll(calibreList), the items in`calibreList`will be copied to the list in the`ComboBox`instead, and its connection to`calibreList`will be lost, and you will need to add items to the list using`getItems().add()` instead.

Comment: i'm instantiating the caliberlist again because a have a new list of two item.  When I call 'new gun' form caliberBox loads the follow calibers: (".38", "357", ".40", "380", "9mm", "12", "7.62", "5.56") if e.g. a user chooses "puma" model, i want the caliberBox become (".38", "357"), for the user choose one or another. I have played with your good tip, but did not solve my problem, I think i need a filter. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see your problem here. If you want the caliberBox, which is a `ComboBox`, to have two options, e.g. ".38" and "357", all you have to do is to make sure to remove the other items from the list. Either you could create a new list with just those two items, and set that as the list of the `ComboBox` by doing `caliberBox.setItems()`. Or you could just clear the `ComboBox` using `caliberBox.getItems().clear()` and then add the new items by adding them one by one by doing `caliberBox.getItems().add(".38")` etc.

Comment: If I'm still not understanding your problem, you might want to edit your post with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get better help.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me, but maybe you did not take a close look on my code example.  modelo is a comboBox, yes it can have two similar items, same model name, that is why the 'puma' model  can have two calibers and I dont wanna add those 2 calibers but remove the others leaving those two. Cant clear either caliberBox neither caliberList because they're inside the FOR statement, getItems().clear() or caliberlist.clear() will always clear one item. I have no time to make a MCVE right now.  As it is just a plus, I will leave the users choose one by one in the comboBoxes. Thanks again!

Comment: I got time to think and fix the problem with help of @Jonatan's  answer. So if somebody else need to do something like that, I fix the code adding the follows line in the 2nd 'if':

Comment: ' }if(list.size()> 1){                                                     
                           cal.add(a.getCalibre());
                           calibrelist.clear();                                                          
                           calibreBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(cal));
                           tipoBox.setValue(a.getTipoArma());
                           marcaBox.setValue(a.getMarcaArma());
                         
                   }' and the cal list before the 'for' statement.